# SharePoint Online Team Site Global Navigation Tier 2 or 3 Child Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, global-navigation

I have a modern Team site, I am able to create or edit links in global navigation (or the top bar hyperlinks).
I am also able to create customised 2nd tier child link. But, when I tried with IE, MS Edge and Google Chrome, zoom out/in, I am not able to add customised tier 3 child links.
In my multiple tries, I only managed to drag and drop once for the tier 3 child link, and, it was not under the intended 2nd tier child link.
Is there any proper or alternate way of creating lower tiers child links?

Comment: Anyone can share if you face the same issue?

Comment: Can anyone guide me on this? As I had tried many times, but still not able to create tier 3 link.  I also came across blog that mentioned mega menu, but it is not available in my team site.